# simple program not working after parallelization

Tags: c++, openmp

I have a simple program, which generates (using `Boost`) some initial velocities and position, and calculates the time it takes to propagate a certain distance. Based on the transverse distances `(x, y)`, the final axial (`z`) velocity is added to a vector. Here is the simple program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/random.hpp>
#include <boost/random/normal_distribution.hpp>

using namespace std;




int main()
{

    boost::mt19937 engine(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)));


    boost::normal_distribution<double> nd(0.0, 1.0);
    boost::variate_generator< boost::mt19937, boost::normal_distribution<double> > normal_std_one(engine, nd);






    double coordX, coordY, coordZ, time;
    double velX, velY, velZ;

    const double factor = 0.01;
    const double distance = 15.0;

    vector<double> cont;

    int i;
    for(i=0; i<1000000000; i++)
    {
        coordX = factor*normal_std_one();
        coordY = factor*normal_std_one();
        coordZ = 0.0;


        velX = normal_std_one();
        velY = normal_std_one();
        velZ = 20.0*normal_std_one()+300;



        time = distance/velZ;

        coordX += velX*time;
        coordY += velY*time;

        if(sqrt(coordX*coordX + coordY*coordY) < 0.02)
        {
            cont.push_back(velZ);
        }
    }
    cout << cont.size() << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

I thought a nice addition would be to parallelize the `for`-loop using `OpenMP`. This I do by adding the following line just before the loop is initiated:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
```

In addition, I have added `-fopenmp` to the compiler options and `-fopenmp* to the linker settings. My program compiles and links without errors, but when I execute the file I get the message:

```
Process terminated with status -1073741819 (0 minutes, 2 seconds)
```

It is not clear to me what I have done wrong here. I am using Windows and g++ (through Code::Blocks IDE).

Comment: You have multiple threads that are simultaneously trying to update the state of `cont`...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth So working with OpenMP is out of the question, if one has to use vectors?

Comment: Does it make any difference if you replace it by cont.push_back[i]=velZ; ?

Comment: @SChepurin That doesn't compile

Comment: Sorry, i meant - cont[i]=velZ; And when something doesn't compile you want to tell the error message output.

Comment: @Schepurin It compiles now, but when I execute the program I am met with the message "The instruction at "0xXXXXXXXX" referenced memory at "0xXXXXXXXX", The memory could not be "written"."

Comment: This is because out-of-range exception you experience. But if you synchronize access with mutex (by #pragma omp critical) you will make it one thread equal without any speedup.

Comment: Using `by #pragma omp critical` and `cont[i]=velZ` gives me the same error message as in my OP

Comment: Frankly, i don't know why it doesn't work as expected with "#pragma omp parallel for" and making it thread safe with "#pragma omp critical" will not bring any speedup with multiple threads. In the end i propose you to use std::thread from C++11 and rewrite code accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I post this as an answer but not comment just to accumulate the results and to avoid long list of comments. It works with `parallel_for` from Microsoft's PPL if you handle `std:vector`'s size properly to avoid `out-of-range` exception. But the problem is when `i` exceeds ~20000, the `boost::variate_generator` cannot handle multiple requests generating `APPLICATION_FAULT_INVALID_POINTER_READ` error with program's crash.

**Update:** When used without `boost::variate_generator` (simply assigning a value to vector's index) on dual core notebook it runs without errors but shows the result the opposite to expected - sequential code runs faster than multithreaded with `parallel_for`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `cont.push_back` unsynchronised across multiple threads. It's not thread safe. You will need to use a different container, or use some kind of mutex lock on access. You may also need to do something to preserve the order they go into the container if that matters.

Comment: The order does not matter in any way. What is your recommendation? I am a beginner with OpenMP.

Comment: I tried making it a critical section by adding `#pragma omp critical`, but now I get the message `"The memory could not be "read"`when executing